# Javascript accordion acting weird

Tags: javascript

When i use jsfiddle to create a simple accordion using javascript, it works fine, but when i use the same code in my .aspx, the accordion is not opening up.  I tried to debug using IE, but of no use.  Any pointer to this will be greatly helpful.

my link to jsfiddle -  [jsfiddle code](https://jsfiddle.net/Lvqde6v3/3/)

```
 var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
        acc[i].onclick = function () {
            this.classList.toggle("active");
            this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
        }
    }
```

and my html:

```
 <div>
 <button class="accordion">
    Q1. Why does CMS collect patient-level
        data?</button>
<div class="panel">
    <p>
        Patient-level data with patient-level identifiers for
    the numerator and denominator of each measure allows CMS to match HEDIS data to
    other patient-level data for special projects of national interest and research,
    such as an assessment of whether certain groups (e.g., ethnic, racial, gender, geographic)
    are receiving fewer or more services than others. These analyses will not be used
    for public plan-to-plan comparisons.</p>
</div>
<button class="accordion">
    Q2. What procedures must I follow to submit
        patient-level data files?</button>
<div class="panel">
    <p>
        Plans need to create patient-level data file(s) 
    conforming to the 2010 Patient-Level Data File Specifications and upload files 
    to CMS via CMS’ Enterprise File Transfer (EFT) infrastructure using an existing 
    Gentran or Connect:Direct account. Alternatively, plans may use a third-party 
    vendor (e.g., Infocrossing) for data file submissions. In either case, the use 
    of Gentran or Connect:Direct is the approved method for patient-level data file 
    submissions.</p>
</div>
<button class="accordion">
    Q3. Where do I find the data file submission
        instructions?</button>
<div class="panel">
    <p>
        It is imperative that each organization confirm their ability to interface with 
    the CMS EFT infrastructure prior to attempting an upload. ior to attempting an upload.</p>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: i showed you the jsfiddle code

Comment: it should be in the question itself.

Comment: It is probably a race condition, jsfiddle executes the js when the dom is loaded, try placing your script tag after the html

Comment: Paste the full code of your aspx page. It's possible you forgot to include the javascript librray link

Comment: much informative answer, andrew, unlike others who negate for showing the jsfiddle link elsewhere...when i placed it after the html, it closes the accordion immediately after the pageload

Comment: @Rob Mulder, even after a link for the js, when i click on one of the accordion panes, it opens and closes right away, on page load.

Comment: @ochi, does it work for you, cos, it doesn't work for me, it closes the panes after the pageload...

Comment: But they also close on the jsfiddle you posted, what is the desired behavior?

Comment: it closes immediately, when tried to open the panes,,that's not the intended behavior, when clicked to open the pane, it should retain that state, not close.

Comment: I see no reason why the code would work any differently to the fiddle, it sounds almost like you have the same js twice, resulting in the class being toggled off and immediately on again

Comment: @andrew : the issue is, it opens the pane, but closes it right away...not sure why it behaves

Comment: @andrew: interesting thing is, in IE, when double-clicked, it retains the state of opening, but not so, in other browsers...

Comment: I don't know without seeing it, are you working on this locally or is it on a public server?

Comment: @andrew: it's my local machine

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue you describe: http://codepen.io/ochi/pen/ozaPNY - are you getting any console errors?

Comment: @ochi, no, I am not getting any, but i resolved by adding jquery UI reference...

Comment: which is why an [mcve] is good to have... voting to close now

Comment: but, i wanted to see if using plain JS would work, and obviously, i couldn't figure it out, why it is not working on my machine,

Comment: We know that plain JS works.  in local machine, how are you serving the files? is it using `file://....` or an actual webserver running locally?

Comment: JS is a inline script on the same .aspx page

Answer (score 0):

I am closing this, since I imported jQuery UI library, and resolved it.